# Can this Java GUI can be simplified?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm writing a Java GUI application, and is something like this:

```
JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(button);
main.add(buttonPanel)
```

I want to add a button to the grid, but i want it centered on the grid panel.
Adding the button to another `JPanel` allows me to center it to the Grid.

Is there any shorter way to do this?

For example:

```
JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
JPanel buttonPanel = JPanel();
main.add(new JPanel().add(button));
```

This is not working for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to make it shorter? Anything shorter and the purpose of your code may become unclear.

Comment: I want to avoid the use of many lines creating a separate JPanel() for each element on the grid, for example my app needs a grid of 7x3, and if a want to center all the elements then i need to create a separate JPanel() for each one. I think is a lot of code, and that's my question, is there a way to avoid creating one by one, or the code conventions says i need to do in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other commenters that reducing the number of lines of code probably isn't as neccessary as you think it is: Generally speaking, your goal should be to reduce code *complexity*, not code *length*, and efforts to minimize length often lead to code that is more complex/hard to understand rather than less.

That said, applying basic OO principles can enable you to shorten your code while maintaining (if not increasing) its clarity:

```
 class CenteredContentPanel extends JPanel { 
      CenteredContentPanel(JComponent addTo){
          this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
          JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
          parentPanel.add(addTo);
          this.add(parentPanel);
      }
 }
```

Now, you can add as many of these as you please to a parent container with a single line of code:

```
  JPanel main = new JPanel();
  main.add(new CenteredContentPanel(button));
  //repeat above line to add as many "centered" components as you need to
```

(code is untested, as I don't have access to an IDE at the moment, but you get the gist...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work perfect. The power of OO. I'll consider reducing lines is not everytime neccesary. Thanks again and this is solved for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add main to the frame:

```
      add(main.add(new JPanel().add(button)));
```

This works fine for me:

```
     import java.awt.GridLayout;
     import javax.swing.JButton;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import javax.swing.JPanel;

      public class MyFrameClass extends JFrame 
      {

    public MyFrameClass(){

   JPanel main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
   JButton button = new JButton();
   add(main.add(new JPanel().add(button)));
   setSize(800,600);
   setVisible(true);


  }
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
   new MyFrameClass();
 }

 }
```